# Parse req.body in POST request

Tags: post, go

I am using `fetch` API to send two values to my `POST` request handler...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/validation', {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email:this.state.email,
            password:this.state.password
        })
```

I want to save both `email` and `password` as strings on the server side. Here is my attempt...

```
type credentials struct {
    Test string
}

func Validate(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)

    var creds credentials

    err := decoder.Decode(&creds)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(creds.Test)
}
```

The problem is I do not know how exactly the format of the structure being sent to the `POST`. I am attempting to save `req.Body` as a string but this yields nothing.

When I print `fmt.Println` I get a blank space. What is the proper way of parsing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
type credentials struct {
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

You are receiving a JSON with two values. Receiving struct should have a structure matching your request. Otherwise, there are no placeholders to decode the JSON into, as in your case - email and password do not have matching struct fields. Btw. if you send `"Test"` in your JSON, this would work, as you have a Test field in your struct!

Regarding field names. If fields in JSON do not start with a capital letter or even have different names, then you should use so called tags. 
More on tags: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

In my example I used them to match struct field names to your json fields, i.e. to make `email` from json match `Email` field of the `credentials` struct.

Answer (score 2):

`req.Body` is an `io.Reader`, and you can get use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) to drain it:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
asString := string(data) // you can convert to a string with a typecast
```

But I'm not sure if that's what you meant by trying to save `req.Body` as a string.

To parse the response into a data structure, you can unmarshal it into a variable of type `*interface{}`:

```
var creds interface{}
decoder.Decode(&creds)
```

And then examine the value:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", creds)
```

Or perhaps using [`pp.Println(creds)`](https://github.com/k0kubun/pp) which I find easier to read.

The `creds` variable will represent the JSON object found in the body, for your example input this will be a `map[string]interface{}` with two entries, presumably both of them strings. Something like:

```
map[string]interface{}{
    "email": email_value,
    "password": password_value,
}
```

and you check the values with:

```
email, ok := creds["email"].(string)
if ok {
    // email will contain the value because creds["email"] passed the type check
    fmt.Printf("submitted email is %#v\n", email)
} else {
    // "email" property was a string (may be missing, may be something else)
}
```

The [documentation of `json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) explains the semantics of how arbitrary JSON strings can be parsed without knowing their structure in advance in the discussion about unmarshalling to interface values.

Comment: Fwiw, the other answer is superior, I misunderstood the part about not being sure what the structure is, the original question clearly specified that the client side code is under the author's control.